# BufferedWriter and Actionlistener not working

Tags: java, swing

I am making a tool in Java that helps record farm records for sales and animals. I have this chunk of code:

UPDATE:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Frame
            JFrame newJFrame = new JFrame();
            //Panel2
            JPanel delta = new JPanel();
            //Panel
            JPanel alpha = new JPanel();
            //Area
            final JTextField beta = new JTextField();
            beta.setSize(20, 7);
            beta.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try{
                        BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("config.plist"));
                        String getInfo = beta.getText();
                        fileOut.write("<"+getInfo+">"+getInfo+"<"+getInfo+">");
                        fileOut.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
```

The program it supposed to create a JFrame when a button is clicked, and then record what is typed into the textField into a .plist file. But when I click it, it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to write a `JTextField` instead of some real text. `JTextField beta` - `fileOut.write("<"+beta+">"+beta+"<"+beta+">");` ?

Comment: `"And its quite obvious what it's supposed to do,..."` -- nothing is obvious when an unknown error is involved. You mention click but then show an ActionListener added to a JTextField. If you need further help, you will want to create and post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This code does not create any `JFrame,` and it does not look like this does absolutely nothing. That would imply no file at all, which would just mean your code didn't execute. Your question remains unclear.

Comment: Yes your newly edited code appears to create a JFrame, create a JPane, create  a JTextField and then does nothing with them. Please post code that makes sense, again what you should create is a minimal compilable runnable example program that we can test, and that shows the error to us, an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Im guessing here: but i think what you want is a button when clicked opens a new window with a textfield and perhaps another button. You write some text in the textfield and press that button and the text gets written to the file right? correct me if im wrong ;)

Comment: YES!! WonderWorld!! That is exactly what I wanted!!!

Comment: So what behaviors are you seeing? Please improve this question. Unless `String someText = beta.getText();` is an adequate answer for your purposes.

Comment: `beta` doesn't appear to be added to anything?

Comment: Thanks all! I fixed it by using all of your advice combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text:

```
String someText = beta.getText();
```

and use the writer to write that string to the file.